# Triangulated manifold implies properties of simplicial complex?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, simplicial-complex, compact-manifolds

I've been told that a compact $d$-dimensional manifold can be realized as a finite $d$-dimensional simplicial complex. Since any manifold is locally compact (I think), if it can be realized as a $d$-dimensional  simplicial complex, is it somehow locally finite? Perhaps in the sense that every simplex is contained in a finite number of simplices?

Can we then also say this sort of statement for locally euclidean spaces which can be realized as a simplicial complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CW-complexes (which cover simplicial complexes as special cases) local finiteness is equivalent to local compactness.

1. Let $X$ be a locally compact CW-complex. Then each $x \in X$ has a relatively compact open neighborhood $U$. The set $\overline U $ is compact, thus contained in a finite subcomplex $F \subset X$. Hence $U$ intersects only finitely many cells.
2. Let $X$ be a locally finite CW-complex. Then each $x \in X$ has an open neighborhood $V$ which intersects only finitely many cells. Hence $V$ is contained in a finite subcomplex $G \subset X$. This is compact, thus $V$ is relatively compact.

Comment: So just to verify, you're saying that the spaces that I mentioned above (Locally euclidean spaces), if they are realized by a simplicial complex, then they are locally finite?

Comment: Yes, manifolds are locally compact. But note that you must require that manifolds are Hausdorff spaces (a standard assumption).

Answer (score 0):

A compact manifold can be covered in finitely many charts (compactness) and we can assume without loss of generality that the domain of each chart is a contractible open set. Does that give you the kind of local finiteness you are looking for?

Comment: This implies that a compact manifold realized by a simplicial complex is finite. I am asking about general manifolds realized as simplicial complexes, and whether we can use this characterization to say that take any finite amount of vertices are contained in a finite amount of simplices.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur If your simplicial complex is finite then it is compact so the manifold is compact as well. If the complex is infinite, it doesn't have to be either. Consider a 2-d simplicial complex which is topologically a surface with infinitely many holes (the genus $n$ surface with $n$ going to infinity). You could make a manifold with that simplicial complex that is locally finite and not compact. Alternatively you could make a manifold that embeds into a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and that is not locally finite by shrinking the holes in a sequence to a point.

Comment: You stated some claims which sound intuitive, but I am unsure how well they translate to a rigorous arguments. How for example can we be sure that such a manifold would not have a locally finite (in my sense) realization?